# How to delete multiple rows in a Collection from Kinvey Console

Tags: kinvey

I am not able to find any option in the Kinvey console to delete multiple records

Is there any option to delete multiple rows in a Collection from Kinvey Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't believe this is currently possible. Please note the new version of the Kinvey console was just released, so there's a good chance it's on the roadmap for future updates.